# Synonyms for 'extra' (noun)

Tags: nouns, synonyms, terminology

Recently I came across the word '*extra*' in following meaning: "a person engaged temporarily to fill out a crowd scene in a film or play".

I have a strong feeling that there should be some synonyms/other words with this meaning.

What are the synonyms for ***extra*** as in the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Walk-on rôle/walk-on part/walk-on player*, *scene part*, *background part*, *spear-carrier* (this last in reference to the extras in historical productions, who add flavour by hanging around carrying an historical weapon), *bit-part/bit player/bit-rôle*.

Answer (score 1):

A less flattering term that was once common is [*bit player*](http://www.usingenglish.com/reference/idioms/bit+player.html) although this has now expanded beyond its original filmic intent. In German, this is Kleindarsteller (small part actor).

Since there was quite a lot of call for *extras* in historical epics with battle scenes, an actor might light-heartedly say "I was just a spear carrier in that one."

Answer (score 0):

[Background actor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extra_%28actor%29), previously called an extra.

[Background performer](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_Screen_Actors_Guild_definition_of_an_Extra) (Screen Actors Guild)